# negative binomial distribution as sum of geometric random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was trying to derive the Negative Binomial Distribution from a Sum of Geometric Random Variables. I was attempting to do this without any MGF's and hopefully from basic summation and series properties if possible.

To begin I made note of what I have: Let $G(X)$ represent a geometric R.V and N(X) represent the negative binomial distribution I am attempting to get:

$$G(X) = (1-p)^{k-1}p \\ N(X) = \binom{k-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{k-r}$$

Where $p$ = probability of event, $k$ = number of trials until success, $r$ = number of successes.

This being stated I tied a simple case where $r = 3$, just to see if I could build from there. In this scenario it would mean 3 geometric random variables being summed together:

$$(1-p)^{k_{1}-1}p + (1-p)^{k_{2}-1}p + (1-p)^{k_{3}-1}p$$

Where each $k_{i}$ represents the number of trials until success for that specific geometric R.V.

With some fiddling I got to this point:

$$\frac{p}{(1-p)}((1-p)^{k_{1}-1} + (1-p)^{k_{2}-1} + (1-p)^{k_{3}-1})$$

Working from the other direction I could get something approaching this form, ignoring the binomial coefficient for the moment:

$$\frac{p^{r}}{(1-p)^{r}}(1-p)^{k}$$

What could I do bring these pieces together, if at all possible? I have a feeling it is actually harder to proceed from here than the algebra I've done up to this point implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do the case of two geometric random variables $X,Y \sim \mathcal{G}(p )$. Then $X+Y$ takes values in $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}= \{2,3,\ldots \}$ and for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$, we have
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(X+Y = n) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{P}(X+Y=n, \, X=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{P}(X=k, \, Y=n-k) \\
&= p^2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-p)^{(k-1)+(n-k-1)} = (n-1)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}.
\end{align}$$
Notice what is happening here: the distribution of the sum $X+Y$ is the *convolution* of the distribution of $X$ and $Y$, and not simply their sum as you seem to be suggesting. (At no point do I have $\mathbb{P}(X=k) + \mathbb{P}(Y=n)$). This can be generalized in the case of $r$ random variables but it gets quite messy, which is why the approach with the MGF and/or characteristic function is to be preferred.

Comment: Didn't take into account the possibility of the convolution, but that makes sense since I'm only superficially familiar with it and haven't really played with the concept. Going to build up the tool kit a bit more and attempt this once I have the convolution idea solidified. Thanks for the explanation.